# error using the code from Mailcomposer from apple sample

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

I using the code from Apple for MailComposer but when I try to run my app i get a error message and I can't build my app.

The message error I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in InfoMailComposerViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Know anybody what this means??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the `MessageUI.framework` in your project.

If you are using Xcode 4:

1. Select the Project then highlight your active Target.
2. Select the "Build Phases" Tab
3. Expand "Link Binary With Libraries"
4. Hit the '+' button
5. Select MessageUI.framework

Comment: Included in your .h? You must include it as a framework in your Project build, not just import the header.

Comment: Hi Mark, I copied and i did add the MessageUI.framework from the apple sample into my project but I have still the same error and my build failed again, thank very much for your effort and comments

Comment: Well, the error is that the framework is not found. My guess is you are not properly adding the framework to be linked. I included instructions above. Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I will try again to adding properly the framework it should be work, i think. thank. You help me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by MarkPowell works like a charm.

I first tried it on the CordovaLib.xcodeproj file.

It did not work, then I tried it at **Testing**.xcodeproj.  Then the errors disappeared and worked magically.